# Magento loading extension from app/code/local but not app/code/community

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We created an extension for Magento and put under app/code/local folder. The extension then loaded properly. But then we move the extension to app/code/community and it no longer works. What we did wrong by moving the extension to another folder like such?

Comment: What's in the module's `app/etc/modules` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `app/etc/modules/namespace_modulename.xml`

Change

`<codePool>local</codePool>`

to

`<codePool>community</codePool>`

Comment: Thanks man, this is exactly the fix that I need. Btw, I want to include this file when packaging my extension. How can I do that? (I don't know what to specify in the extension packaging setting wizard so that app/etc/modules/namespace_modulename.xml can be included)

Comment: this is the guideline for packaging the magento extensions.May be this can help. http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf